# cmake - how do i do add_cd_file but for directories

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I am trying to add cygwin to the reactos project. everytime i try doing

`add_cd_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cygwin DESTINATION reactos/cygwin FOR all)`

It fails because it is not a file, I have tried to use `copy` but that just copies the file, it does not add it to the destination. So my question is how do I do something like this `add_cd_dir`?

Comment: What is `add_cd_file`? Where does it come from? It is no CMake command but must be part some other project.

Comment: it is i think its part of reactos, hmm let me look, I think you might be right.